# qTip content load fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins, qtip

How to handle content loading failure in example like this:

```
 qtipTo.qtip({
            content: { url: 'EditSchedule'}
```

action method:

```
   public ActionResult EditSchedule(int? id)
    {
        if (id.HasValue)
        {
            var schedule = _fService.GetSingle(id);
            if (schedule != null)
            {
                return View("EditSchedule", schedule);
            }else
            {
                return Content("Unable to load correct data. Maybe the element has been deleted.");
            }
        }
```

So basically that's how it works now, but how can I handle it better? If there is no schedule found, qTip shouldn't even get opened.

Comment: What do you mean by `something`? Could you post the actual error?

Comment: To Jakub's point, more information would be helpful, but I suspect that the issue is that you may have to return "false" in order for qTip to not show.  Or you may have to check the validity of the content in the qTip show event handler and abort its display there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend handling this scenario by using the `onRender` method and doing an ajax call yourself.

```
qtipTo.qtip({
            api: {
                onRender: function () {
                    var api = this;

                     $.ajax({
                         type: 'POST',
                         url: '/EditSchedule',
                         success: function (content) {
                             api.updateContent(content);
                         }
                     });
                 }
             }
        });
```

Now you can handle any sort of failure in the success callback.